# Why do we add a function $g(y)$ at the end of a partial differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

I am working through PDEs and the textbook I am using gives the example of:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3y^2+x$

Which is then re-written as:

$f(x, y)=\int (3y^2+x)dx+g(y)$

My assumption is that this is, because $y$ is treated as a constant, our constant of integration will then be $y$, i.e. the term we use for our constant. I am also assuming that because we can treat $y$ implicitly as a function, this is reflected as $g(y)$.

However, these assumptions of mine feel a bit vague and I'm hoping to understand a little more substantially.

Grateful to find out where my assumptions are incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

It is no different than adding the usual constant $C$ in taking antiderivatives of functions of a single variable. In taking the antiderivative of the expression

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3y^2+x$

with respect to $x$, the partial derivative wrt $x$ of any function $g(y)$ will be $0$ hence adding this "constant" completes the solution set.

Also note the proper partial notation ($\partial$ not $\delta$).

Comment: Awesome thank you this really helps!